# Smooth transition between two (class) and (class):hover

Tags: jquery, class, transition, smoothing

Is there a script/way, that makes normal CSS `:hover` more smooth?

Idea would be, that you got two classes maybe with gradient backgrounds, and the script would smoothly swap the classes. So the gradients would look like your pressing a button. Should be automatic, so you call the trigger: `$('.someclass').SmoothTransition();` and it would automatically use the `.someclass:hover` as the second class.

---

**Bounty edit**

This is actually a very interesting question that got a partial answer by me. The problem with my answer is that, it works only for solid background color and doesn't work with CSS gradients or any other more specific parameter.

This script should be a 'must-have' in any jQuery developers library. So, I'm offering 150 rep to anyone, who can think of a way or find good resource, that can do this.

If your method (single jQuery plugin) works for all these examples, then you have won!

**Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/4pYWD/**

---

**Modern days edit**

Since this question was asked in 2011, when CSS transition, is commercial game was not an option. Then understand, why everything is focused on JS and not CSS, in this question. From these answers, I developed a JS script, that was at the time, perfect. Its not anymore, CSS transitions are the ultimate solution now, so the proper answer got re-accepted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [css3 transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) to achieve that.

An example:

```
a {
    color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
```

You can check out this alive [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bluefoot/CEtfh/).

The example was given with static colors, but you can use [css3 gradients](http://css-tricks.com/5700-css3-gradients/) as well:

```
a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
}

a:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7 5%, #2F2727, #1a82f7 95%, #2F2727);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7 5%, #2F2727, #1a82f7 95%, #2F2727);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be FF4+ only. Thats bit of a problem.

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention that. Well, if it is not a must-have requirement in your project, you can let the users of the old browsers without the smooth transitions, since it doesn't affects accessibility. In some projects, actually, is not worth to maintain JS code for that.

Comment: Technically this is for an admin area, but there's usually a high need for this kind of method, for all sort of projects.

Comment: No, not all browsers support transitions, however, you can use Modernizr to test for that, and provide a jQuery fallback in case it doesn't.

Comment: @bluefoot You should have a `transition:` line sine that'll eventually be the spec, hopefully.

Comment: @Josh agreed (edited) and hopefully the syntax would be the same.

Comment: I checked this out on my designers computer. Basically this is a great solution, however even modernizer cant fix this. So still, until we live in the better days and can make smooth transitions VIA HTML.. we have to use jQuery :(

Comment: @kalle Unless you are using an active community-maintained plugin, I think that's too much code to maintain for a single non-functional requirement.

Comment: I agree with you. It would be perfect, if similar function would be included in the jQuery core. However, currently I found a solution that btleffler provided. This could be adopt to so many things.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/btleffler/MZ6T8/

Works in Chrome, Safari for Windows, and Opera. Firefox and IE have shoddy support for CSSRules objects, so the results are iffy at best. I'll keep working on it to see if I can fix  the issues though.

The css styles need to be tweaked too. Since there's no background color assigned to the `:hover` selector on the last example, there's no background color on the new element.

If anyone has some ideas for this stuff I'd love to hear them.

---

**EDIT: FIXED**

http://jsfiddle.net/btleffler/JfPBS/

This one works better. I search through all the css rules for `:hover` selectors, then I save the CSS text associated with that rule, and the non :hover rule as a javascript object that can be plugged into `$().css()`. After that, I compute the actual "hover class" by using `$.extend()` to extend the hover class on to the normal class. This way, if there's no background defined in the `:hover` class, it will still have the background from the normal class.

Finally, I create an element, and position it directly under the original element, get rid of what makes CSS handle the hover, add my normal style to the original, and my computed hover style to the new element under it.

All we need to do after that is animate the opacity on mouse events. Simple!

Comment: I'm thinking that if instead of strictly working with CSSStyleRule objects, I could just copy their styles directly to the elements. Probably more simple that way and should work better in other browsers.

Comment: Fixed it. Works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE!

Comment: Dude, nice! I remember few back, when I created some hardcore plugins for 50 bounties:D I guess that karma paid off. I'm basically not gonna analyze it, has on the first glimpse it meets all my given requirements and I can see the amount of work on the plugin. You won it straight up! The ID and CSSRule problem is minor and can be bypassed. Thanks a thousand! :)

Comment: You're welcome! It was a learning experience for me. Very interesting question. I wish there more people messing around with the idea.

Comment: Well, if you agree to, then people can modify it and improve it. Sooner or later this will be picked up by jQuery people and hopefully it will be included in the jQuery core. Because, I think most who saw this question, can agree.. that such plugin does have a high need.

Comment: I hope you understand, I will re-accept this question as I found more optimal and try method. Your method seemed fine, but uses too much resource (scamming trough the hole stylesheet) and didn't work with background-images. However, I would be very happy if you have some comments on how to improve it :)

Comment: Nice work. But man, what a hell of a mess for a single effect!

Answer (score 1):

http://desandro.github.com/motion-emotion/ This project allows for transformations in all major browsers except ie7 and ie6. It has progressive enhancement for those 2 browsers

Answer (score 0):

So the solution what I was looking for is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").hover(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("blue", 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    p { margin: 4px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bolder; cursor:pointer; color: white; background: yellow;}
    .blue {background: blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="">Hover over this</p>
</body>
</html>
```

See the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/uRJWG/

NOTE: Does not work with css3 gradients. But still..

Comment: I think this is linking to another thing.

Comment: you probably would want to accept your own question, since it was how you solve it. Check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

It's really rough, but I've got a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk8gX/2/) that should be one that (in theory) works across browsers and with whatever image you want. Right now it is a bit hacky (read extremely), but it's a good place to start, and will maybe get people on the way to a full answer. Also, it doesn't work at the moment if you do it quickly. The button must fade in or out completely before the mouse comes off the element. Like I said, hacky but a start.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally figured out the most ULTIMATE way to have smooth transition on hover. I hope this will help others with the same problem. My current tests show, that this works 100% for all examples I could come up with. Works for hyperlinks and normal containers.

**[Download from GitHub](https://github.com/kallevaravas/kvSmoothTransition)**

This plugin has 3 options.

- **showSpeed:** [number] - easein animation speed
- **hideSpeed:** [number] - easeout animation speed
- **includeText:** [boolean] - determines if the html from the element will be used

If you have ideas on how to optimize this plugin, then contact me or leave a comment :)

Comment: Since this was in 2011, when transition support was limited, then this answer is extremely outdated and transitions in CSS, ARE the ultimate method. Then I re-accepted this questions, CSS answer.